# Retrieve saved (NSUserDefaults) date to another class

Tags: objective-c, nsdate, nsuserdefaults

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:datePicker.date forKey:@"birthDate"];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setInteger:sexSegmented.selectedSegmentIndex forKey:@"sex"];

[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
```

This is the value that I am saving to **userdefaults** and from another class I want to call them.

```
NSDate *birthDate = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"birthDate"];
NSInteger a=[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] integerForKey:@"sex"];

NSLog(@"%@",birthDate);
[datePicker setDate:birthDate animated:YES];
sexSegmented.selectedSegmentIndex=a;
```

This is the other class from where I am getting the saved values, but I can't see any value in **birthDate**. I want to take it and set the new **datePicker** to **birthDate**. Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's most likely a case of the interface outlet of `datePicker` not being connected properly. This would make `datePicker` `nil` and as a result you would end up storing `nil` in the user defaults.

You can validate this by doing

```
NSLog(@"%@", datePicker);
```

before your first snippet of code.

Comment: First thanks for reply that is really helpfull i did what u said it give me something like <UIDatePicker: 0x17fd70; frame = (0 249; 320 216); autoresize = W+BM; layer = <CALayer: 0x17fed0>> this i double check the ib connections any idea what is this thing means

Comment: This means everything's connected. What does the `NSLog(@"%@", birthDate);` log?

Comment: 1996-07-01 08:03:36 +0000 i choose the date ofcourse thanks i can see it in same class now i take all the second snippet of the code from diffrent class i want to set the date that i choose from other class with the second part of the code but still uidatepicker didn't show this date it is still waiting in default value

Comment: saving is already working yes but am i doing a mistake in code (second snippet) to see the date from another class

Comment: Since it is logging correctly, have you checked the `datePicker` in the second class i.e. the connections and have you tried logging like before?

Comment: Yes i check them i write the second part of the code into the viewDidLoad part when i click the tab icon of the new class still the datepicker didn't show the date i choose before